# Solspace Friends - Status Updates Display

Tags: solspace, status

Is there a way to display all status updates from a particular member group in templates irrespective of whether or not they are friends (of the logged-in user)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to display all statuses of members in an EE member group. However, you can get this data using the EE query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_friends_status AS f 
    JOIN exp_members AS m ON m.member_id = f.member_id
    WHERE f.group_id = 5"}
  {status} by {screen_name}<br />
{/exp:query}
```

...where **`5`** in `f.group_id = 5` is the EE member group_id from which you want all the group's member statuses to be displayed.

Note: *The above is to display statuses of members within a **EE member group**, not a **Friends Group**. For a Friends Group, the query would be different.*

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! How can I put an item limit on this though?

Comment: You would add `LIMIT 50` to the query inside the `sql=""` parameter, where `50` is the maximum number of results you want to display.